# IMacros random choose

Tags: firefox, random, imacros

Each time I run the script, I am trying to select at random one from the following:

```
TAG POS=1 TYPE=IMG ATTR=SRC:photolink1
TAG POS=1 TYPE=IMG ATTR=SRC:photolink2
TAG POS=1 TYPE=IMG ATTR=SRC:photolink3
```

This is probably quite an easy questions - this is my first project with this program.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
SET !VAR1 EVAL("var options = ['photolink1','photolink2','photolink3']; var string = ''; for(var i = 0; i < 1; i++){string += options[parseInt(Math.random() * 3)]}; string")

TAG POS=1 TYPE=IMG ATTR=SRC:{{!VAR1}}
```

this should work to randomly choose one of the options.

Comment: thanks ! it works . can i get any contact  ? skype or something ?

Comment: You can mark my answer as accepted if its the answer you were looking for.
If you need any off-topic help leave your email (hope its not against site rules) and ill contact you

Comment: `VAR1` could be much easier to eval: `SET !VAR1 EVAL("'photolink' + (Math.floor(Math.random()*3) + 1);")` .